# EF: Select columns where any of them has value but not all of them

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

Below is my code to retrieve some data based on the following criteria:

```
allMembers.Where(Function(x) Not x.firstDate Is Nothing Or
                             Not x.secondDate Is Nothing Or
                             Not x.thirdDate Is Nothing).ToList()
```

This will bring me the data where any of the columns has value (not null)

My problem is, this code will also fetch the records where all three columns have values. I need to filter those records, where all three columns has values and get those where either of three columns have values.

any ideas?

Comment: did not get do you need those recorda where all three records are in nothing?

Comment: no, I want to get the records where any of the three columns has value but not all three of them at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    allMembers.Where(Function(x)  Criteria(x)).ToList()


function Criteria (x as YourType) as boolean
 dim test as int =IF(x.firstDate Is Nothing, 1, 0) +
                  IF(x.secondDate Is Nothing, 1, 0) +
                  IF(x.thirdDate Is Nothing, 1, 0)

 return test > 0 and test < 3

end function
```

Comment: allMembers is a list(of myEntity). Is there a simpler way to filter those records that have all three records?

Comment: By the way, this works. Although the solution does not seem to be the correct and most effective way where it could have directly been solved within the linq query itself, I do like the idea of using functions as it is the first time I am seing such a thing and can imagine a lot of scenarios where I see myself using similar approaches. Hence, I am accepting the answer.